# Sort columns of a data.frame based on a list of prefixes

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Names       S1_ATTCG    S1_GTTA     S9_TGCC     S5_TGGA      S21_GGCA    
   A           0.34       0.12        0.32        0.98          0.65   
   B           0.14       0.02        0.45        0.09          0.006   
   C           0.04       0.34        0.98        0.12          0.06
```

Is there a way to sort the columns so that the columns beginning with ^S1 and ^S5 will appear before all the others?

The data frame is composed by 53.000 columns and 12.000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution:

```
cbind(
      d[, grepl( "S1|S5", names(d))],
      d[,!grepl( "S1|S5", names(d))]
     )

  S1_ATTCG S1_GTTA S5_TGGA Names S9_TGCC S21_GGCA
1     0.34    0.12    0.98     A    0.32    0.650
2     0.14    0.02    0.09     B    0.45    0.006
3     0.04    0.34    0.12     C    0.98    0.060
```

With data:

```
d <- read.table(text = 'Names       S1_ATTCG    S1_GTTA     S9_TGCC     S5_TGGA      S21_GGCA    
   A           0.34       0.12        0.32        0.98          0.65   
   B           0.14       0.02        0.45        0.09          0.006   
   C           0.04       0.34        0.98        0.12          0.06   ', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
d <- read.table(text = 'Names       S1_ATTCG    S1_GTTA     S9_TGCC     S5_TGGA      S21_GGCA    
   A           0.34       0.12        0.32        0.98          0.65   
   B           0.14       0.02        0.45        0.09          0.006   
   C           0.04       0.34        0.98        0.12          0.06   ', header = T)


d[c("Names", gtools::mixedsort(names(d)[-1]))]
#>   Names S1_ATTCG S1_GTTA S5_TGGA S9_TGCC S21_GGCA
#> 1     A     0.34    0.12    0.98    0.32    0.650
#> 2     B     0.14    0.02    0.09    0.45    0.006
#> 3     C     0.04    0.34    0.12    0.98    0.060
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

or

```
d %>%
  relocate(gtools::mixedsort(names(d)), .after = Names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Good ol' `dplyr` can help too.

```
d %>%
  relocate(
    starts_with(c('S1','S5')), .after = Names)
  )


  Names S1_ATTCG S1_GTTA S5_TGGA S9_TGCC S21_GGCA
1     A     0.34    0.12    0.98    0.32    0.650
2     B     0.14    0.02    0.09    0.45    0.006
3     C     0.04    0.34    0.12    0.98    0.060
```